# Cannot read String response of Retrofit and RxJava POST request

Tags: android, post, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-java2

Api Interface

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("register.php")
Observable<String> registerUser(@Field("email") String email, @Field("password") String password);
```

In my MVP presenter

```
onCreate{
  Observable<String> registerUserObservable= 
  apiInterface.registerUser("test@gmail.com", "1234");
  registerUserObservable.subscribeOn("schedulers.io())
         .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
         .subscribe(this::handleResult, this::handleError);
}

//methods
private void handleResult(String response){
  Log.d(TAG, response);
}

private void handleError(Throwable throwable){
  Log.d(TAG, throwable.getMessage());
}
```

These are my code for retrofit and rxjava and I am suppose to post an email and password to register a user. The server should return a string on success and a string on failure too.

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
           .setLenient()
           .create();

retrofit = new retrofit2.Retrofit.Builder()
           .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
           .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
           .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
           .build();
```

I added the gson setLenient code portion because it gives me 
`Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 2 column 1 path $` error if I don't have it. After adding this, I am getting `JSON document was not fully consumed.` error which I do not know how to solve it. Is this because of the return response from the server is a string?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: there is likely something wrong with the format of the response. if `Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 2 column 1 path $` comes up at all - you likely aren't getting valid JSON in response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your server sends normal string response not JSON string, you need to use another converter that reads string into `String`. Happily there is [Scalars converter](https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-converters/scalars) officially.

> A Converter which supports converting strings and both primitives and their boxed types to text/plain bodies.